# Setting environment variable in ubuntu and checking in python

Tags: python, ubuntu, stanford-nlp

Using `gedit` I added the following line to `bashrc`

```
 export CLASSPATH="/home/standford/some.jar"
```

`bashrc` already contained the following line:

```
export PATH="/home/alex/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

Now when I execute in python:

```
import os
print(os.environ.get('PATH'))
print(os.environ.get('CLASSPATH'))
```

I get back:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
None
```

How do I get `CLASSPATH` to show up? This is all part of the following instructions:[stanford core nlp](https://blog.manash.me/configuring-stanford-parser-and-stanford-ner-tagger-with-nltk-in-python-on-windows-f685483c374a)

Comment: You need to `source` your bashrc first

Comment: @cricket_007 What does it mean to source bashrc?

Comment: You either need to "re-import" the bashrc with `. ~/.bashrc` or just restart the shell for the changes to take effect. Note that the dot command (`.`) is an alias of `source`.

Comment: @Anonymous I tried both `source ~/.bashrc` and `. ~/.bashrc'. Nothing worked. I am going to reboot and see it would help

Comment: Are you sure you're editing the correct file? You should be able to see changes right away after sourcing by doing `echo $CLASSPATH`. If you can't see it like this, python won't see it either.

Comment: @Anonymous. `echo $CLASSPATH` returns correct value

Comment: Then `python -c "import os; print(os.environ['CLASSPATH'])"` and your script should work too.

Comment: @Anonymous. Your code works in terminal, but anaconda jupyter returns `KeyError: 'CLASSPATH'`

Comment: @Anonymous, regular `jupyter python` works fine too.

Comment: Probably should have mentioned that in the original question. I have no idea what that is.

Comment: Try to get a [mcve] of Python reading environment variables. And without going through Jupyter because that has its own environment variable settings

Answer (score 3):

Your environment variable is not exported.Before you run your code ,run bashrc script

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 2):

You can't use spaces when assigning variables in the shell.

```
$ export X = 1
bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `1': not a valid identifier
$ export X=1
$ echo $X
1
$ python -c "import os; print(os.environ['X'])"
1
```

Comment: I removed all the space, but it did not help. I actually did not have space, I retyped incorrectly here when was posting this question